# Why does IE7 not like this bit of Javascript?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

the code below works on IE 8 and 9, plus the versions of FF and Chrome I've tested it on, but not IE 7. On IE 7 I get the error '**object doesn't support this property or method**' occuring.

Here's an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve:
The array contains objects which describe the pages of a book. I want to be able to iterate through the array as a user goes through the pages of the book. 
The reason I went with array of objects instead of object full of objects was so that I could access the information about a page by using the page's number as the array key. (e.g. to get page 3's picture I'd call pages[3].pic). 
The prevPageID and nextPageID are kind of replicating the functionality of a linked list, as sometimes not all the pages are available to to viewed and these variables show the next available pages viewable from the current page. pic is the location of the page's picture, secondsLeft and purchased are just purchase data.

I can't figure out why this is. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance :-)

```
var pageId = 2;
var pages= Array();
pages[1] = {   
                prevPageID: 15, 
                nextPageID: 2,
                pic: "1.jpg",
                secondsLeft: 0,
                purchased: 0 
            };
pages[2] = {   
                prevPageID: 1, 
                nextPageID: 3,
                pic: "2.jpg",
                secondsLeft: 0,
                purchased: 0    
            };
*timeLeft = pages[pageId].secondsLeft * 1000;*//Error occurs on this line
```

Comment: because it is IE7.  You'll run in to a few things that work differently.  If you explain what  you're trying to do then we can help with the workaround for IE7

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation, if it's not enough, or unclear, please say so and I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at index 0, not index 1. This could be your problem.